# Are there any tutorials/documentation for lsp-java?

Tags: java

I have managed to install lsp-java according to their git Readme (https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-java) and created my workspace.

Is there a better way (eg. in form of a documentation or tutorial) to get to known with lsp-java or do I have to try out every single possible command and see what is going to happen?

Comment: Are you already familiar with Emacs?  It looks like the package assumes that you are.  If you're not, do `C-h t` for the Emacs tutorial. If you already are, and the README doesn't give you the information you need, it's a good idea to start with `C-h m` or `describe-mode`.   That should tell you the relevant bindings.  From there use `C-h f`, `describe-function`.  It's convention to name Emacs packages with a prefix.  For `lsp-java`, it's `lsp-`.  Do a `C-h f lsp-`.  If the package is any good, the functions should be intuitive and the docstrings helpful.

Comment: If you find the package useful, yet the documentation lacking, write up the documentation you would have liked to see (using your hard-won knowledge).  Your input is valuable!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680711/how-to-do-a-github-pull-request

Comment: Does googling for `"lsp-java" tutorial` help?

Comment: If it helped, I would not have asked here :)  I even disabled looking for Liskov's Substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [github page](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-java) for lsp-java, there is a [wordpress page](https://xpressrazor.wordpress.com/2020/11/04/java-programming-in-emacs/) that runs through an example workflow utilising lsp-java. This could be a good starting point.

Comment: That page now also has a link to a fantastic video demo: https://youtu.be/Bbjxn9yVNJ8

Answer (score 1):

I'm using configure of prelude and install lsp-java recently without much configures:

1. require lsp-mode, company-lsp, lsp-ui, lsp-java;
2. add code for hook:

```
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook #'lsp)
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'company-mode)
```

3. create a test java project with git and HelloWorld.java;
4. restart emacs and open HelloWorld.java by step3, emacs will auto download jdt(you may download it manually);
5. when everything ready, you should see message like "LSP :: Connected to [jdtls:12693 status:starting]." when you open HelloWorld.java by step 3.

all my configure can find at: 
https://github.com/RezoChiang/prelude/tree/rezo-lsp/modules

Comment: Where should you put the downloaded `jdt-language-server-latest.tar.gz` and how to install it manually?

Comment: I am also having the same problem. How to install the language server manually

Comment: sorry for reply sooo late. there should be eclipse.jdt.ls/server under . emacs.d you can put the jdt file to there.